# Use top based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a parameter in my stored procedure that specifies number of rows to select.  (Possible values: 0-100. **0 Means Select All rows**)

For example `@Rows = 5;`

Then I can do this:

```
Insert into @MyTableVar   
   Select Top(@Rows) * 
   from myTable
```

Now, as I said before if 0 is supplied I need to return all rows.
This is a pseudo-code of what I need:

```
if (@Rows=0) then select * else select top(@Rows) *
```

I found out that there's [SET ROWCOUNT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx) that accepts 0 to return ALL rows, but I need to do an insert into a table variable which is not supported by `ROWCOUNT`.

Is it possible to achieve this without dynamic sql?

(I understand that I can write a simple if else statement and duplicate query, but I have pretty complex queries and there are lots fo them, I just want to avoid code duplication)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to just put a big number in:

```
set @Rows = 5;
declare @RowsToUse = (case when @Rows = 0 then 1000000000 else @Rows end);

select top(@RowsToUse) * from myTable
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are missing the `ORDER BY` clause, since you are using `TOP`. You could do this:

```
SET @Rows = 5;

WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id) --put the right order here
    FROM myTable
)
INSERT INTO @MyTableVar
SELECT YourColumns
FROM CTE
WHERE RN <= @Rows OR @Rows = 0
```